# Is there a way to get prolog to print out data structures more nicely?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to print out this:

`[sentence([nounp(_G2571,[noun(_G2571,buffalo)],subject),verbp([trans_verb(buffalo),nounp(_G2587,[adj(buffalo),nounp(_G2587,[noun(_G2587,buffalo)],object)])])])]`

In a way that makes it more readable.

It's supposed to be a parse tree of an English sentence, and I want its output to be readable to humans. Is there something built-in to prolog that would let me do that? I know the gui debugger will print it nicely but I'm looking for a way to print it to standard out.

Answer (score 1):

SWI-Prolog has some tools to produce nicely formatted terms, like [gvterm](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=gvterm), but if you just want to indent your structure, this code could do

```
indent(I, S) :-
       is_list(S)
    -> maplist(indent(I), S)
    ;  ( atomic(S) ; var(S) )
    -> format('~s~w~n', [I, S])
    ;  S =.. [F|Args],
       format('~s~w~n', [I, F]),
       maplist(indent([0' |I]), Args).
```

for instance

```
?- indent([],[sentence([nounp(_G2571,[noun(_G2571,buffalo)],subject),verbp([trans_verb(buffalo),nounp(_G2587,[adj(buffalo),nounp(_G2587,[noun(_G2587,buffalo)],object)])])])]).
sentence
 nounp
  _G7615
  noun
   _G7615
   buffalo
  subject
 verbp
  trans_verb
   buffalo
  nounp
   _G7638
   adj
    buffalo
   nounp
    _G7638
    noun
     _G7638
     buffalo
    object
```

*edit*

SWI-Prolog has also [print_term](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/pprint.pl)/2: the default settings already performs reasonably

```
?- print_term([sentence([nounp(_G2571,[noun(_G2571,buffalo)],subject),verbp([trans_verb(buffalo),nounp(_G2587,[adj(buffalo),nounp(_G2587,[noun(_G2587,buffalo)],object)])])])], []).
[ sentence([ nounp(A,[noun(A,buffalo)],subject),
         verbp([ trans_verb(buffalo),
             nounp(B,
               [ adj(buffalo),
                 nounp(B,
                   [noun(B,buffalo)],
                   object)
               ])
           ])
       ])
]
```

Comment: print_term doesn't seem to be working for me. :/ It doesn't seem to be a defined procedure.

Comment: maybe are you using an old SWI-Prolog version ? sorry... my snippet is easily customizable. and should be portable on most Prologs with ease